# Rigid body physics problem even a torus acts like it had no hole in it

Tags: physics

When i apply rigid body modifier after punching a hole in a cube for inserting a rotatable propeller so that it rotates only when something collides with it.

But when i run the simulation the propeller shaft pops out of the hole and the cube behaves like it had no hole in it, even after after selecting "mesh" for the shape of physics body.

[image: the cube with hole]

Comment: Double check normals, apply transforms, also.

Comment: Also, rigid body physics doesn't work well for curved surfaces in close contact with each other - such as shafts and axles. If objects are constrained by each other in such a way, use Rigid Body Constraints. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101880/29586 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/108843/29586

Answer (score 3):

By default the shape of rigid body collisions is set to 'Convex Hull', if you want the the collision shapes to include holes you need to set the collision shape to 'Mesh':

[image]

However like it is indicated in the comments, if you need objects constrained to each other you should use Rigid Body Constraints, otherwise you might not be able to get a smooth simulation without errors.

Comment: You are correct. I missed that. It seems I cannot replicate the issue then. However if Convex Hull is selected as Collision shape everything matches the description of the problem perfectly. Maybe double checking that the correct objects have this setting is not a bad idea.

Comment: Missed it too at first: removed  initial comment that suggested same. Agreed, does pay to double check.

Comment: i had selected mesh for rigid body shape i know that it is set by default as a convex hull.

Comment: Please share a .blend file then. It works as intended no matter what I do trying to recreate the issue.

Comment: Problem solved when i scaled up everything .